# Do not show relations to invisible tables in SchemaCrawler diagram

Tags: schemacrawler

I use schemacrawler-14.16.03 on Windows 7.
My command is:

```
schemacrawler.cmd -server=postgresql -host=hostname -port=5432 -database=db -schemas=public -user=user -password=***-sslmode=require -loglevel=INFO -outputformat png -infolevel=standard -command=schema -outputfile=somefile.png
```

I want to show a group of tables with relations between them. I edited schemacrawler.config.properties schemacrawler.table.pattern.include and easy got only tabels I need. But a diagram contains all relations beetween these tables and other tables (invisible at diagram).

I tried to change different config options but unable to hide these relations. How can I hide them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another way you can try out. In `schemacrawler.config.properties`, let `schemacrawler.table.pattern.include` include all tables (`.*`).

Use the following `-grepcolumns` trick shown below to include only the tables you want, and use `-only-matching` to exclude links to invisible tables.

Try the following command on a single line:

`schemacrawler.cmd -server=postgresql -host=hostname -port=5432 -database=db -schemas=public -user=user -password=*** -infolevel=standard -command=schema -only-matching -grepcolumns=.*\.(YOUR TABLE PATTERN)\..* -outputfile=somefile.png`

Sualeh Fatehi, [SchemaCrawler](http://www.SchemaCrawler.com)

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thank you!
Also I note that you may need to insert grepcolumns pattern in double quotation marks. I got "The system cannot find the path specified." from cmd without them.